# Java Double Multiplication explanation?

Tags: java, double

I recently tested something out that I heard using the following code

`public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = 4.35 * 100;
        System.out.println(x);
    }`.

I am interested as to why this produces 434.99999999999994 rather than 435.0 . Thanks

Comment: It's a problem of precision.

Comment: There's like a zillion questions about floating point precision on SO already...

Comment: Double values are imprecise, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707397/whats-wrong-with-this-simple-double-calculation/16708068#16708068

Comment: 4.35 is 100.010110011001100110011001(10011001)..... recurrring, i.e. not exactly representable in binary. You'll always have small errors in the last few decimal places

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you type:

```
double x = 4.35;
```

`x` is not stored as-is. It is stored in a approaching form (probably 4.349999999 in this case).

If you want exact result, please use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

You can learn about the [accuracy problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) of floating-point technology.

Comment: Even with BigDecimal, I'm facing problems. Consider this,BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(4.35);         System.out.println(bd.multiply(new BigDecimal(6)));