# Is it compulsory to use BigDecimal for counting currency (Java)?

Tags: java

is there any chance that PC adds 2 decimal float numbers incorrectly?

```
0.13 + 0.21 =0.340000000004
```

If we human adds these 2 number then we won't have any extra fraction error right? cos it 's not logic, but Computer could have.

Is this Computer problem?

How to use BigDecimal in Java properly?

Comment: Just use `int`, or `long`, and count in cents, not dollars (or whatever currency you have).

Comment: what do you mean by ***PC***? It is a floating point issue...

Comment: you must know that when we're talking about floating point numbers, 0.13 is not 0.130000000000000000000000000 and 0.21 is not 0.2100000000000000000000000000

Comment: I don't understand why so many down votes, this is a question that indeed confuses a lot of people

Comment: Try adding 1/3 to 1/3 in decimal and then tell me humans do a better job. This may be an interesting read: [Why does for loop using a double fail to terminate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907186/why-does-for-loop-using-a-double-fail-to-terminate/19907216#19907216) or [Whats wrong with this simple 'double' calculation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16707397/2187042)

Comment: @cahen - I agree. Upvoted the question :-) Made an explanation why this happends further down

Comment: @cahen Downvotes are because the question shows no research effort. A quick search on Google or Wikipedia already answers. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I get it now, and I agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The floating point arithmetic has been a problem since long. That is why the usage `BigDecimal` is encouraged. To your question on how to use it properly, I've a simple example which can help you understand how [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) can be used along with [MathContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html).

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(0.13); // double value to BigDecimal
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal("0.21"); // String value to BigDecimal

MathContext mc = new MathContext(3, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN); // first arg is the precision and the second is the RoundingMode.

BigDecimal bd3 = bd1.add(bd2, mc); // perform the addition with the context

System.out.println(bd3); // prints 0.340
```

Comment: uhow to convert String into BigDecimal?

Comment: @Tum - BigDecimal has many overloaded constructors which takes in pretty much all primitive data types and also String as an argument. I edited the answer to reflect the same.

Answer (score 3):

It is not compulsory, but it is good practice for four reasons at least:

1. currency sums can grow arbitrarily large (suppose you work for a bank, you **do not** want the system to go crazy on overflows). While a billion $ might seem a large sum, consider that in some currencies a billion or even a trillion might not be *that much*.
2. float numbers are subject to erosion because of floating point approximation. Still in the bank example, you **do not** want to steal or give away cents on any transaction and you want the bank account to be empty, not containing `1e-37$`
3. float numbers have limited precision. While this is ok for most applications, when processing currency, you want to keep track of everything, from billions to cents.
4. float numbers have states that are meaningless when dealing with currencies: what does it mean that a client deposited `NaN` dollars?

Answer (score 0):

Its because the conversion to binary is not even. Same as the fraction 1/3 becomes 0.33333333 when using decimal-system

The standard for floation numbers is called IEEE 754 and uses 32 bits

these 32 bits consist of the following parts

- sign = 1 bit (0 = + ,, 1 = -)
- exponent = 8 bits
- mantissa = 23 bits

You could check this out by visit

http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=048046051052

so when convert 0.34 (as an example) to binary it becomes

```
 00111110 10101110 00010100 01111011
```

and when the computer converts it back the result in the decimal-fomrat is not exactly the same:

```
 00111110 10101110 00010100 01111011

 3.400000035762786865234375E-1
```