# why does this variable return negative value?

Tags: anylogic

i have a variable with initial value : 34-64*0.4-7*1.2.[image: image1]

It should appear 0,instead the result is negative. Could you please tell me the reason? thanks
[image: image2]

Comment: please consider the equation in the image .thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how variables are stored in Java.

`double` variables are precise up to a certain number of decimals digits. In your equation, while none of its parts exceed 1 decimal, rounding is done in the binary format causing this very minor inaccuracy at the 16th decimal.

-1.776E-15 is equal to -0.000000000000001776.

Here is an interesting thread that can give you more insights on the topic:

[Whats wrong with this simple 'double' calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707397/whats-wrong-with-this-simple-double-calculation)

One thing you can do to overcome your problem is to round off the error using:

```
roundToDecimal( 34 - 64*0.4 -7*1.2 , 14 )
```

This would round your number to 14 decimal places thus rounding off the inaccuracy.